# How do I conduct an analysis by row ID where each row will be resampled (reanalyzed) 10 times before moving on to the next row in R?

Tags: r, random

I'm a beginner in R, and am working through data where I need to randomly sample from a von Mises distribution 10 times per row. I have already calculated the concentration parameter (kappa) of my data, and am using rvm() from the package CircStats to generate random samples. For each real observation, I have a von Mises mean (in degrees, "Example" column below):

Obs    Example
1   1   69.43064
2   2  -41.80749
3   3  133.83900
4   4  -12.82486
5   5 -137.57358
6   6  -19.27882

Therefore if I were to calculate a random sample of 10 from a von Mises distribution with a concentration parameter (kappa) of .44, my code for the first observation would look like:

> rvm(10,rad(69.43064),.44)
>    [1] 0.7695183 5.9182905 2.6174674 5.6028430 2.4213428 5.4660423 6.1753582
>    [8] 2.6910969 4.2964024 5.4806146

I want to refer to the observed mean in the data, so:

> rvm(10,rad(BearEx$Example), .44)

I'm looking to calculate 10 random values per observation. My ideal output would look like:

Obs Random
1   0.7695183
1   5.9182905
1   2.6174674
1   5.602843
1   2.4213428
1   5.4660423
1   6.1753582
1   2.6910969
1   4.2964024
1   5.4806146

And so on with each observation. I feel like this is a pretty basic problem, but I'm having trouble coding that loop with the observation number.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a data frame of the observations and their means ex:

```
obs_plus_mean = data.frame(obs = 1:5, mean = c(69.43064, -41.80749, 133.83900, -12.82486, -137.57358, -19.27882))
```

Then for a somewhat robust solution you can start by making a function that takes input of kappa, the sample mean and sample size n to generate a sample of size n for each observation. For convenience you can even put your default values for kappa and sample size.

```
von_mis_sample = function(mean, size = 10 , kappa = .44) { 
  sample = rvm(size,rad(mean),kappa)
}
```

Then you can compute your samples by the call

```
samples = sapply(obs_plus_mean$mean, von_mis_sample(mean))
```

(In your case I think you want BearEx$Example instead of obs_plus_mean$mean here)

---

That should work, please let me know otherwise.

Comment: Ah! Got it. I had a minor issue on my end (as a beginner) and incorrectly interpreted a part of your code. This worked great!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Great! No problem. For future reference may I know what part you incorrectly understood ?

Comment: Actually, just one more question - to I want to have all these generated samples in a csv where column 1 is observation number and 2 contains the random values. I'm linking these sample to real data, so observation data helps me compare appropriately. I've tried few ways, but all result in observation number being jumbled in. Any pointers?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your previous comment first. I adjusted this part:
samples = sapply(obs_plus_mean$mean, von_mis_sample(mean))

to this: 
samples = sapply(obs_plus_mean$mean, von_mis_sample)

just removing the (mean).

Comment: Ah yeah that is important a call to the function, couldn't have helped you there.

Could you clarify what how you want to the csv file to look ?

Comment: I got it! I used the 'reshape' package to "melt" the data and "cast" it to look like I wanted to.

Comment: Nice! Good job.